# PHP error with th colspan

Tags: php

This is my current php script to show table standings I keep getting errors on my page when I try to add colspan="2" to stretch the header

```
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `standings` WHERE division = 1 ORDER BY TotalPoints DESC;") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 Print "<table border cellpadding=10 width=500>"; 
 Print "<tr><th colspan="2">CONLEY</th></tr>";
  Print "<tr><th>Team Members</th><th>Points</th></tr>"; 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 

 Print " <td>".$info['TeamMembers'] . "</td> ";
 Print " <td>".$info['TotalPoints'] . "</td> </tr>";

 } 
 Print "</table>";
```

Comment: Posting the actual error messages might help us pinpoint your problem. Also where do you want to add the `colspan="2"` bit? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to escape you quotation-marks, otherwise they will break the string and cause an error:

```
Print "<tr><th colspan=\"2\">CONLEY</th></tr>";
```